# Return the x value of a div's positioning in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically I have an unordered list, and each list element has a div inside it that can slide left and right inside that list element.  All of that works fine, but I want to be able to compare the x positioning of the divs to make it so that if any two overlap on the x axis, they both turn red.

```
function checkForOverlap(){
  $("ul#jobs").each(function(){
        var   $this = $(this);
              job = $this.children(":first");
              sib = $this.siblings(":first").children(":first");
        console.log(job.width()+" "+job.css("left"));
        });
}
```

My thoughts are if I can get the left of one, I can compare that plus its width to the left of its sibling.  All that job.css("left") returns is

```
auto
```

Is there a way of getting the x position of a div? Is there a way to compare all the div x coordinates together or should I just compare each  to its siblings (the list is sortable so i can move all the elements around and check each one with each sibling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the question as is there an x position?  Yes. it is called the object.offsetLeft.  However, you have to be careful because the x value of that offset is within its parent.  This means that is parent has an offset, also and if you add all the parent's offsets up you will get the x value or offset for the screen.

```
function checkForOverlap(){
  $("ul#jobs").each(function(v){
      v.offsetLeft //for the elements offest
      v.parent.offsetLeft // for the parent's offset
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking all over for something like position() or left(), did not realize that it might be listed as offset().  I'm really new to all this :)